# How to run zipkin on another ip address than localhost when starting server with "java -jar zipkin.jar"

Tags: spring-boot, zipkin, armeria

Did saw [this](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/issues/1772)...
But I'm not able to make it run, whatever I have tried, I get either still on localhost, either an exception on armeria bind ( I have stuff running on :8080) and server crash...

In short what I have tried (Windows Server 2016, so no Linux Docker containers ) with no avail. Variation on these batch file commands:

> SET "SERVER_ADDRESS=xx.xx.xx.xx"
> SET "ZIPKIN_HOST=xx.xx.xx.xx"
> java -jar zipkin-server-2.23.2-exec.jar --armeria.ports[0].port=9411 --> armeria.ports[0].protocols[0]=http

It should be simple to run Zipkin on another ip, but I'm fighting. Could you help me, maybe I'm missing something absolutely obvious... But is a pretty common scenario, and is not that well documented.

Answer (score 0):

`server.address=<ip>` does not work?

`java -jar zipkin.jar --server.address=192.168.0.7`

If it's not working you can add a property file and connects to it when the server starts:

`java -jar zipkin.jar --spring.config.location=./application.properties`

in application.properties:

```
armeria:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      ip: 192.168.0.7
      protocol: HTTP
```

Comment: Does not work:
java -jar zipkin.jar --server.address= IP change this goes ignored
java -jar zipkin.jar --spring.config.location=./application.properties changes the IP when I added server.address=.... in the file, changed also the armeria port since I have something on 8080
But got a couple of screens of errors but the jist is "Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind"
Tried to leave just the port, still changes the IP for armeria but same error.
For some perspective these are the installed Java:
-8 Update 281
-SE Development Kit 15.0.2 (64-bit) and 11.0.10

Comment: So you have another service on 8080, but you want to serve the Zipkin server on 8080 with a different IP on the same machine. Is that what you want?

Comment: I want zipkin on another ip than localhost.  On a public one, and there on 8080 is another service that I cannot move.